# Intuit QBO SDK Update Bill error generating the XML document Value of ItemElementName mismatches the type of System.Decimal

Tags: sdk, xml-serialization, quickbooks-online

I am using Intuit QBO SDK v3 Intuit.Ipp.QueryFilter.QueryService(Of Bill) to get a collection of Bills filtered by Bill.Id.  The collection is populated successfully.  I want to modify just the BillableStatus of some of the ItemBasedExpenseLineDetail members of a Bill and update it with Intuit.Ipp.DataService.DataService.Update(Of Bill).  Whether I actually modify any properties of the Bill or not, the Update method generates the following error:

Intuit.Ipp.Exception.SerializationException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Value of ItemElementName mismatches the type of System.Decimal; you need to set it to Intuit.Ipp.Data.ItemChoiceType.@UnitPrice.
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterBill.Write163_ItemBasedExpenseLineDetail(String n, String ns, ItemBasedExpenseLineDetail o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterBill.Write181_Line(String n, String ns, Line o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterBill.Write185_Bill(String n, String ns, Bill o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterBill.Write186_Bill(Object o)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(Stream stream, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces)
   at Intuit.Ipp.Utility.XmlObjectSerializer.Serialize(Object entity)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Intuit.Ipp.Utility.XmlObjectSerializer.Serialize(Object entity)
   at Intuit.Ipp.Core.Rest.RestHandler.PrepareRequest(RequestParameters requestParameters, Object requestBody, String oauthRequestUri)
   at Intuit.Ipp.DataService.DataService.Update[T](T entity)

The values of all the ItemBasedExpenseLineDetail members of the Bill seem to properly be Intuit.Ipp.Data.ItemChoiceType.UnitPrice as shown by a Watch or Immediate Window, for example:

?DirectCast(qboItem.Line(0).AnyIntuitObject, Intuit.Ipp.Data.ItemBasedExpenseLineDetail).ItemElementName

UnitPrice {2}

Any ideas how to perform the update without this error or where to look further?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Aaaaaand, about as soon as I posted this question, I found the answer over on Intuit.Developer Community

> I guess you have the default setting from SDK where request format is XMl and response is Json.
>
> This causes serialization issues which you have mentioned above.
>
> Please add the following lines in your code to have either both request/response in xml or boht in json format.
>
> context.IppConfiguration.Message.Request.SerializationFormat = Intuit.Ipp.Core.Configuration.SerializationFormat.Json;
>
> context.IppConfiguration.Message.Response.SerializationFormat = Intuit.Ipp.Core.Configuration.SerializationFormat.Json;